# Using a European (GSM) cell phone in the US

Tags: usa, cellphones, roaming

I have an HTC A9s. I could not find it on the US page of the manufacturer so I went to the [UK page](https://www.htc.com/uk/smartphones/htc-one-a9s/).

According to the specs, it does have the US frequencies:

```
Network4

2G/2.5G - GSM/GPRS/EDGE:
850/900/1800/1900 MHz
3G UMTS (#UL):
850/900/1900/2100 MHz
4G LTE (#UHL):
FDD: Bands 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8,12, 17, 28
TDD: Bands 38, 40
4G LTE (#UL):
FDD: Bands 1, 3, 7, 8, 20
```

Will I be able to use it in the US for calls and Internet?

Comment: HTC is not European company...

Comment: @9ilsdx9rvj0lo in this context it clearly means "For the European market"

Comment: realistically you need to use AT&T

Comment: lycamobile.pl is a good "everywhere" sim these days

Comment: @Fattie T-Mobile should work perfectly fine given it supports the 1900 MHz legacy GSM and UMTS network, and their primary LTE bands 4 and 12. This phone covers the same T-Mobile US bands as an iPhone 7 purchased directly from the carrier.

Comment: @user71659 T-Mobile uses some unique frequncy bands many smartphones (event if bought in the US) don't support. It will work but 3G and LTE coverage will be sparse without thouse bands. I used both T-Mobile and AT&T, and AT&T worked far better for me.

Comment: Please avoid talking about roaming costs, SIM card availability etc which are off topic. The question is very technical and asks for the ability of the HTC A9s to get signal from an US base station with regards to difference in frequencies. It has been answered from the technical point of view. This comment is directed to answerers and commenters of answers.

Comment: @dusky Not really. T-mo always ran 2G and 3G at 1900, nothing weird. This phone is missing band 66, which is downlink only, so it won't affect coverage. Band 71 is not available for use; TV stations have yet to move off. Sprint is the one with weird bands and TDD. This phone supports absolutely zero Sprint network bands.

Comment: @user71649, That's not right. T-Mobile originally ran 2G exclusively on 1900 and 3G exclusively on 1700 (i.e. AWS). The UMTS AWS band was often missing from many European phones (as it is from the OP's) which is why AT&T was a better bet for them. Now, however, T-Mobile seems to have generally reused all the AWS spectrum for LTE (band 4) while moving the 3G service to 1900 in most markets, so the missing 3G 1700 band on European phones is less of an issue.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Many years ago, it was highly unlikely that a European cell / mobile phone would work in the US.

More recently, but still quite long ago, your phone might work if it supported the US bands.

In both cases, the answer might have varied from state to state or city to city.

These days, you are unlikely to experience a problem.  Phones are now much more standardised than in the early days.  I have not experienced a problem roaming in the US for a long time.

To be absolutely sure you would need to check with your current service provider and research ones in your destination area.

I suggest that you check roaming charges carefully: they might be very high, especially for data.  You might want consider getting a local SIM card.  How easy this is seems to vary a lot.

Comment: My situation is the reverse: I'm a US citizen who travels to the UK, but this answer exactly matches my experience. Getting a UK SIM card for my US GSM phone has worked for me without issue. Getting a local SIM card also makes it easier for everyone else to get a hold of me, secure in knowing they won't be charged exorbitant long-distance fees.

Comment: @turibe Yes, things are much easier in both directions these days.  I would expect my answer to work both ways.  The issue that is more complex is acquiring a local SIM card.  The ease of this varies a lot from place to place.

Comment: @turibe The exception is if the people calling you are in your country of origin instead of at your destination, in which case getting a local SIM at your destination will make the call international for them instead of local. :)

Comment: @reirab: so you get a dual-SIM GSM phone and have both a US and local SIM. These are common. Btw T-Mobile postpaid allows cheap international roaming and free international texts.

Comment: @smci Yeah, I know you can get dual-SIM, but at least the last time I was in the market for a phone, most U.S. smartphones weren't dual-SIM, even the high-end ones. I haven't looked at what's out there in a while, though, so perhaps it's more common now.

Comment: @reirab It's irrelevant what devices US carrier stores offer (discounted and locked), when you can easily buy something technically superior from Amazon, eBay, OnePlus, Samsung et al. US consumers are ridiculous for playing along with carriers' practices of selling discounted (single-SIM) phones locked to a single network. It's illegal in the rest of world. Keep your carriers honest - never ever buy a locked phone and never buy a single-SIM phone. Google Pixel (/2) is inferior to other Android phones in this regard. In Asia it's common to have two SIMs: one for domestic and one for data/IDD

Comment: North America still uses a largely disjoint set of frequency bands from Europe. One of the reasons I replaced my wildfire S before a trip to Canada was because it did not support any of the 3G bands used in north America.

Comment: I have had a couple of dual SIM phones.  This is because I travel to Asia frequently and they are easily available there.  Here in the UK, I have never seen one in a shop but you can obtain them through the net.  I have mixed opinions on their value.  Convenient in some ways but it is easy to make a costly mistake by calling out on the wrong line.  An alternative is to carry two phones. I tend to use an older lower tech one for my home SIM and my current phone for the local SIM.  So, my instinct is to use the current phone and this unlikely to be a costly mistake.

Comment: I have my second dual sim phone, current an online buy from China, last an older model on sale in NL, both allow to set the data use to one of the sims only, to only have calls go out from one sim (the same or the other) and/or for each number which sim to use.

Comment: @Willeke Yes, those features are available and if carefully used make mistakes less likely.

Answer (score 10):

In addition to the other answers:

1. Check the roaming charges for your provider/subscription. They can be extraordinarily high. The biggest issue is data, as your phone can use **a lot** of data without you even noticing or even doing anything actively on your phone (background updates of apps, e-mail...).

   Providers often given data rates using units such as MB or even KB. 0.10 €/MB doesn't seem much, but when you use a few hundred MB per day, that easily adds up to hundreds. Some others will include calls and data for some destinations, but there may be a cap, or a threshold beyond which they start charging per MB.
2. If you decide you definitely want to be able to use voice & data while in the US:

   - check that international roaming is enabled with your mobile provider. Some enable it by default, some don't. Some may require a deposit or something similar to enable it. It may vary depending on your contract.
   - check for any relevant "add-ons" which may reduce your costs.
   - check that your phone has roaming and/or data roaming enabled (the two settings may be in different places).
   - monitor your usage.

Comment: Can only agree on the cost checking for data. I know of roaming data bills for 15000$ for 'checking facebook'.

Comment: The UK Three network has "feel at home" for many of its contracts which allows you to use your phone in many countries without any roaming charges.  This includes the USA. This roaming use includes calls, texts and data but not using the phone as a WiFi hotspot.

Comment: @anomuse That's still less than what my Finnish operator charges for roaming data in the US (12,49 €/MB). Fortunately there is a cap, cutting the data once a threshold is reached, but that means just a couple of MB.

Answer (score 10):

This is an excellent site I'd visited to figure out which SIM cards would work on my parents' Mi A1 phones in Canada - https://willmyphonework.net/.

If you are looking for roaming, it *might* be expensive. You are probably better off getting a US SIM (T-Mo, Ultra Mobile etc.) and using it for the duration of your stay. Your choice, of course, but just a suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

yes your phone will work also in the US.
Regarding internet: you should have the option for data roaming active, otherwise it will not connect to the data network.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, GSM phones will work in the US, either on GSM carriers (at&t, T-Mobile) or their resellers (MetroPCS etc.) or MVNOs (Virgin Mobile, LycaMobile etc.)

To solve the dilemma of international roaming for call/text/data, **get a dual-SIM GSM phone and install both a US and local SIM**. These are common (OnePlus, Samsung, Huawei, Xiaomi, Honor etc.) Obviously, when you're in Europe, turn off data roaming on your US SIM (and restrict or disable bandwidth-hungry apps), and vice versa.

Btw T-Mobile postpaid allows cheap international roaming and free international texts in most foreign countries. As long as the T-Mobile postpaid account has been active domestically in the US for the preceding n [*] months, and the foreign usage does not exceed fraud threshold. [*] T-Mobile reps have quoted me numbers anything between 1-6 months.

Answer (score 2):

Not all European GSM phones work in the US (regardless of the SIM card). In fact I tried to use one of my GSM flip phones (bought new in 2015) in New York and it just said "no network", it didn't even have the possibility for emergency calls.

Part of the relevant information is here on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM_frequency_bands

Europe uses GSM 900 and 1800 ("dual band").

America (not only the US. Also Canada, South America, Central America) mostly uses GSM 850 and GSM 1900.

Smart phones are typically quad band phones. I assume the manufacturers don't want to bother with different models for different parts of the world, or nowadays, the possibility to use your smart phone everywhere is far more important than with "cheap" phones that could only text and phone - after all for these services you also need a decently priced plan, or might just be unavailable (time zone difference, vacation, …) or get a throw-away phone in the country you're visiting.

You already collected the relevant information about what GSM standards your phone can do, and in fact all relevant ones are covered.

Comment: This is true but no longer very relevant. 2G GSM service may in fact be gone in the US [(here's AT&T's announcement of their shutdown)](http://about.att.com/innovationblog/2g_sunset) while most Canadian carriers never had a 2G GSM service to start with. 3G UMTS service is now quite ubiquitous but is used on a somewhat different set of bands than you list. Most people interested in data roaming would prefer 4G LTE service anyway because it is faster.